# Conditional Statement causing input to not work

Tags: javascript, input, conditional-statements

I am trying to make a text adventure game and I want the game to be able to tell what room the player is in. to do this I added a if else statement inside my function called "game" that checks the value of the variable "room" then only runs the respective switch based on the value. but for a reason I do not know once I added the if else statement now nothing happens when I press enter.

How do I implement this if else into the game so it can identify what room the player is in without screwing up my input?

any help is GREATLY APPRECIATED

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en-US">
        <head>

            <meta charset="utf-8"/>

            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

            <title>The Dungeon of Agkorak</title>
        </head>

        <body>
            <h2>"Welcome to the Dungeon of Agkorak!"</h2>
         
            <p id="output">You stand in a large open field, to the north there is a cave entrance in the side of a hill. 
                <br>There is a mailbox there. <br>What do you do?
                                                  </p>
            <input type="text" id="input" autofocus>
            <script>
                const output =document.getElementById("output");
                const inputField = document.getElementById("input");
                var room = 0
                

                //this function will handle user input

                function game() {
                    const input = inputField.value.toLowerCase(); //allows for case insensitivity


                if (room == 0) {
                    switch (input) {
                        case "walk to cave" || "walk north":
                            output.innerHTML = "You walk up from the field to the cave entrance";
                            room = 1
                            break;
                        case "walk to mailbox":
                            output.innerHTML = "you walk to the mailbox";
                            room = 1
                            break;
                    
                        default: 
                        output.innerHTML = "invalid command";
                    } 

                } else if (room == 1) {

                    switch (input) {
                        case  "enter cave" || "enter":
                            output.innerHTML = "inside the cave you see painting on the wall";
                            room = 2
                            break;
                        case "look around":
                            output.innerHTML = "nothing of any real interest";
                            room = 1
                            break;
                    
                        default: 
                        output.innerHTML = "invalid command";
                    } 


                    
                } else

                //function to allow enter key for input
                inputField.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
                    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
                        game();
                    }
                });
            }
            </script>  
            
                    
                     

                    
                
        </body>
     </html>
```

I tried to implement a if else statement into my function "game" in order to have it check to see what room the player was in before checking player input. before I put in the if else the game worked as intended, I would put in the correct string value and hit enter and the game would return what I wanted. but after I put in the if else it did not do anything when I hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

and welcome to SO! You are using `room = 0` and `room = 1` which will actually change the value of `room`. Try using `room === 0` and `room === 1`. Learn more about JavaScript [equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) here.

Comment: I just changed the if else for this `` if (room == 0) and if else (room == 1) and it did not work still have the same problem